# create minimal spanning tree using table of distances between nodes rather than TSP

Tags: pgrouting, transportation

I am working on a transportation (linear programming) problem. Each potential solution also requires checking the distance of approx 20,000 routes with 5 to 15 nodes per route.
Calculating the shortest path for each route is likely to be time consuming using a TSP or similar call in pgrouting.

Would it be feasible to sacrifice some accuracy (for example < 10%) and instead build a minimal spanning tree for each route using a pre-calculated distance table of the shortest path from one node to another (say using OSRM).

Apologies if answer is blindingly obvious, I am new to GIS.

Comment: I work with linear programming and routing issues. I'm still not clear on what you're trying to achieve